# PHP Contact Form message not displaying in E-Mail

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have PHP script that works fine. When the email is sent, everything works fine except for the message. Here's what I get in the email:
    New Mail from:

```
 Name: asdf 
 Phone: 9879879879 
 Email: asdf@dfsg.com 

 Project Location: asdf 
 Message:
```

As you can see, the "Message: " doesn't show what was typed in the form. Here is the code:
    
    
    Cotnact form
    
    body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

## Contact

Variables/
    //Type in your email address to receive the mail
    $to = "ironspeed12@yahoo.com";

```
//If you wish to show a logo in the mail, paste the URL here.
//For example: http://mywebsite.com/mylogo.png
//Remember http://
$logo_url = "http://arniesremodeling.com/Logo1.png";  
/*VARIABLES END*/
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/','', $_POST['name']);
$phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/',"", $_POST['phone']);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$location = preg_replace('/[^ A-Za-z0-9,\-]/',"", $_POST['name']);
$message = preg_replace('/[^ A-Za-z0-9,.?\-]/',"", $_POST['message']);
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if($name == "" or $phone == "" or $location == "" or $message == ""){
echo'One or more fields has not been filled out.<br>
Please go back and try again.';
}
elseif(strlen($phone) != 10){
echo'Invalid Phone Number.<br>
Please enter a valid phone number.';
}
elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo'The email address could not be validated.<br>
Please go back and verify your email address.';
}
else{//All checks passed
if(isset($logo_url) and strlen($logo_url) > 3){
$logo = '<img src="'.$logo_url.'" alt="" style="border:none;"><br><br>';
}
else{
$logo = "";
}
$headers = "From: Arnie's Remodeling";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message = '<html><head><style>body {font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;}        </style></head><body>';
$message .= "$logo
New Mail from:<br><br>
Name: $name <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Email: $email <br>
IP: $ip_address <br><br>

Project Location: $location <br>

Message:<br>
".nl2br($message)."

</body></html>";
$sendMail = mail($to, $location, $message, $headers);
if($sendMail){
echo'Thank You, the mail has been successfully sent!<br><br>';
}
else{
echo'An error occurred and the mail could not be sent.<br>
Please try again later.';
}
}
}
else{
header("location:contact.html");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are overwriting  $message variable after defining $headers

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that lol thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reuse the `$message` variable. First you set it to this:

```
$message = preg_replace('/[^ A-Za-z0-9,.?\-]/',"", $_POST['message']);
```

And then a few lines later you set it to this:

```
$message = '<html><head><style>body {font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;}        </style></head><body>';
```

For a quick fix - replace the first line with:

```
$mess= preg_replace('/[^ A-Za-z0-9,.?\-]/',"", $_POST['message']);
```

And then at the end of the script use this:

```
".nl2br($mess)."
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed it. I hadn't noticed that I was overwriting the $message variable. Thank you to both you and guri for helping me on this one!

Comment: @saty sorry, I was just waiting for the time limit to get to 0 seconds